# Visual Studio 2008 Standard: No Windows Service project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-services

I own a copy of Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition, and I'd like to create a Windows Service. However, I don't have a Windows Service project template. According to [this chart](http://download.microsoft.com/download/5/f/e/5feb6914-bcdf-432f-81c7-e386812b086a/VisualStudio2008-ProductComparison-v1.08.pdf), Standard Edition should be able to create Windows Services. I tried running devenv.exe /InstallVSTemplates, but I don't seem to have any of the Windows Service templates (which is probably why the devenv command didn't work).

Does anyone know how I can get the templates?

Comment: You can create a service without the template as well.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder why people ask here before googling... Here's the very first result from searching  `"visual studio 2008 standard" services`: http://justinjmoses.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/visual-studio-2008-standard-vs-professional/

Comment: @Cogwheel: Your top-voted question and answer are your own self-promotion (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515399/can-you-make-custom-operators-in-c) and you still have a problem with people asking genuine questions, even if they are basic?

Comment: I did Google first. I always do. I tried '"Visual Studio 2008 Standard Edition" "Windows Service"', as well as a few others. I didn't find anything as helpful as the link you posted, though. I guess I was too specific.

Comment: @Mike: It's a common problem that once you know the correct answer, it's easy to write a search that finds it.  There was evidence that you'd actually tried because you told us what didn't work; there was no call for the insulting tone in the other comment.  Posting that URL as an answer would've been appropriate, however.

Comment: Wow... Sure there was some snark in my comment, but I think you're over-reacting a bit here, @Roger Pate. @Mike Pateras, I'm sorry if my comment came across as insulting as Roger seems to have taken it.

Comment: @Roger Pate: wow you really got a stick up your butt about this one. You really down voted my other question/answer because of some personal vendetta against me? Luckily for my sense of irony I care far less about my rep SO rep than you seem to (if I did care, I would indeed have posted that link as an answer)

Comment: @Cogwheel: No, I down-voted it because it's self-promotional spam.

Comment: Umm ... ok... It's also community wiki, and I mentioned someone else's project first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the templates.  Just create a class that inherits from `ServiceBase` and in your `Main()` method call `ServiceBase.Run()`.

You can use a console project and use command line options or `Debugger.IsAttached` to decide whether to run as a service or not.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that not including the template in the Standard edition was an oversight on Microsoft's part. Check out [this Microsoft forum thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/thread/52885523-e912-4d93-a09d-5333bb3e99c8/) where someone was kind enough to post the template that you then simply install with `devenv /installvstemplates`