# How can I declare an infix exponentiation operator for C++?

Tags: c++, operators

Is there any way I can declare an operator `**` such that `a**b == pow(a, b)`? Maybe using some preprocessor macro trickery?

Comment: IIRC: You cannot define new operators. What's wrong with `pow`?

Comment: What is wrong with typing those couple extra characters so that future readers will know what is going on?

Comment: If you give it a proper name, [sort of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515399/can-you-make-custom-operators-in-c). With the literal `**`, nope.

Comment: [This](http://www.stroustrup.com/whitespace98.pdf) might be a interesting read for you

Comment: Would `a *pow* b` be acceptable?