# C++ how to create special type of operator

Tags: c++, c++17

I created a class Marks and + operator.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Marks {
    int intmark;
    int extmark;
public:
    Marks() {
        intmark = 0;
        extmark = 0;
    }
    Marks(int im, int em) {
        intmark = im;
        extmark = em;
    }
    void display() {
        cout << intmark << endl << extmark << endl;
    }

    Marks operator+(Marks m) {
        Marks temp;
        temp.intmark = intmark + m.intmark;
        temp.extmark = extmark + m.extmark;
        return temp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Marks m1(10, 20), m2(30, 40);
    Marks m3;
    m3= m1 + m2;
    m3.display();
    return 0;
}
```

I want to change the operator + to something different.

I mean:
The operator will run if:

> m3= m1 + m2;

but could i change it to something like that

> m3 = m1 specialoperator m2
> I don't whan there the + sign.
> Could i change it on some sentence or number operator?
> m3 = m1 11--11 m2
> m3 = m1 -MYoperator- m2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you make custom operators in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515399/can-you-make-custom-operators-in-c)

Comment: You cannot change the precedence rules for operators.

Comment: In C++, **We can overload only existing operators and cannot invent new operator symbols**. So for example, we cannot define `operator**` to provide exponentiation.

Comment: @jjramsey Hi. Thanks for the answare. Yeah, it help me lot. Also thanks other for answare.

Answer (score 1):

In C++,

> We can overload only existing operators and cannot invent new operator symbols.

So for example, we cannot define `operator**` to provide exponentiation.

Similarly, we **cannot have** `m3 = m1 11--11 m2;` and `m3 = m1 -MYoperator- m2;`