# Is it possible to add extension for 'is' operator in C#?

Tags: c#, operator-overloading

Is it possible to implement method to call like

```
if (myString is Email)
```

where `Email` is a class name and actual validation is performed under "is", not just type checking.

Not for real world projects, just curious.

Comment: No. You can't override the `is` operator. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: If Email is a class, cant you change the question to if (Email.IsValid(mystring)) and have as much logical readability?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Its overloading and not overriding

Comment: @BugFinder Yes,  totally. I was not looking for an actual solutions, just thinking about possible syntax sugar. Thank you for attention.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: I always thought the official docs didn't make much sense for calling it overloadable operators but you just made me realize why it's overloading and not overriding. Cheers ;)

Comment: Predicting future interesting questions, [click](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1040114/1997232).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't because `is` operator cannot be overloaded. Read [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx)

Why don't you create a custom extension method and check in that method.

Answer (score 1):

You may find useful a partial solution via *operator*:

```
  public class Email {
    ...
    public static implicit operator Email(String value) {
      if (...) // validate value here
        return null; // <- not an actual Email

      // Email
      return new Email(value);
    }
  }

  ....

  Email email = "SomeAddress@SomeServer.com";

  if (email != null) {
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Also a little confusing because of null, but thanks for your attention.